# Tag name proposal

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-synonym-process

I've recently started the new tag [non-instantiated-argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/non-instantiated-argument), for questions about Prolog's *"ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated"*, and there are [*plenty* o' those](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprolog%5D+not+sufficiently+instantiated+is%3Aq) already. They are coming at a steady pace, too.

The name might not be the best, though. So please, your suggestions.

Comment: Who is an expert in that specific error but not Prolog generally? Who would follow a tag for a single error? What's the point, basically?

Comment: Given that they apparently aren't bothering to search for the error message, what makes you think the tag will make any difference? The problem isn't that the tag doesn't exist, it's that the people asking are lazy, incompetent or both.

Comment: There are a lot of questions about javascript, maybe we should create yet another javascript tag for the excess.

Comment: Went through the first page of this tag, you personally added the tag on all of them, is this a thing when having a new tag?

Comment: Is there a canonical post about that error, or does it make sense to make one? Thereafter, most or all of them can probably be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Well I've never been part of a new tag start procedure, so I didn't know that meant personally editing other people's posts just for the sake of adding a too specific tag

Comment: @WillNess yes, of course, but you didn't mention that in the question (or for eight hours afterwards...) and surely the need here is a good canonical dupe target (which there may already be) not a tag wiki that the same people who don't search for error messages will never read.

Comment: Given that my comment has had about as many upvotes as your question has downvotes, can you really not put two and two together? You have presented a *fait accompli* and asked if the name's OK rather than bothering to check if the tag was a good idea in the first place, which makes answering tricky.

Comment: meta ***bad***. I did in fact seek, and received, helpful input from community, specifically from those *knowledgeable* in the matter at hand. The new tag (with the name close to the one proposed in the *accepted* answer) is alive and well in use now, a year later. So, yeah.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The common phrases for this phenomenon are "not sufficiently instantiated", "uninstantiated" or "not instantiated".  The term "non-instantiated" is rather uncommon.

Related ISO errors are called `instantiation_error` (when an instantiated term is expected but not found) and `uninstantiation_error` (where an uninstantiated term is expected but not found).

So using `instantiation_error` as a tag seems more appropriate.  It would certainly help to answer such questions in a more compact manner by referring to further similar cases.